# How to execute user-defined function that accepts and returns another?

Tags: scala

Here's my function:

```
def partial1[A, B, C](a: A, f: (A, B) => C): B => C = (b: B) => f(a, b)                    
> partial1: [A, B, C](a: A, f: (A, B) => C)B => C
```

Here I invoke the function `partial1`:

```
def fun(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
> fun: (a: Int, b: Int)Int

val r = partial1(1, fun)                       
> r  : Int => Int = <function1>

r(fun(1,3))                                     
> res0: Int = 5
```

So `r` is a function which takes a function as parameter and returns a `Function1` (a function with 1 parameter). Should `Int => Int` not be  `Int, Int` since two `Int`s are the function parameters?

Why can't I implement `Partial1` like `partial1(1,(fun(1,3)))` which causes compiler error : `type mismatch; found : Int required: (?, ?) => ?` ?

Comment: At which position the type mismatch occurs?

Comment: (Scala compiler usually prints the problematic line of code and points to a specific location in this line.)

Comment: @Sarge Borsch error is caused at line "partial1(1 , fun(2,3))"

Comment: at which position _in this line_?

Comment: @Sarge Borsch Scala worksheet is not displaying line position

Comment: aah… okay. I didn't know about Scala worksheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `partial1` isn't a partial function. It's a function that returns another function so it's a higher-order function.

The compile error you're getting is because `partial1` expects a function `(A, B) => C`, but you're passing `fun(1,3)`, which evaluates to an `Int`. And `Int` is not the same as `(Int, Int) => Int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ex03 {
  def partial1[A,B,C](a:A, f:(A,B) => C): B => C = f(a,_)
}

class ex03Test extends UnitSpec {

  behavior of "partial1"
  it should "return 6" in {
    val e = new ex03
    val multiplyByTwo = e.partial1(2, (a:Int, b:Int) => a * b)
    multiplyByTwo(3) mustBe 6
  }}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are not considered as helpful as code with explanatory text. If the question is old and already has an accepted answer then it helps to understand what your answer adds to the issue. In this case you appear to have missed the point of the question. The OP knows how to invoke `partial1` in a manner similar to your example but was asking about a different form of invocation that doesn't work.